# Media recorder - Android Java Call recording receiver voice is too low

Tags: java, android, call-recording

I'm using Media recorder  in android  Java for recording  calls,but the  receiver voice is very very low for the audio source as MIC. Do we have any other option to increase the receiver quality ?